# the number of regionservers is not expected as configured

Tags: hbase, region

In my hbase cluster, I set 5 hadoop datanode `s1,s2,s3,s4,s5` in `regionservers` file, and set the hadoops namenode `m1` in `master` file, but when I start the hbase cluster, I can only see 2 regionservers `s1,s3` on the hbase-status page? what's the problem?
so far the hbase cluster is working properly. I've checked the DNS but found no probelm.

Answer (score 0):

Check if all the regionservers are up on not by doing a "sudo jps" on each host, if not go and start individual RSes from the init script